# Plot axes invisible when projected

Tags: plotting

When I save plots made in Mathematica in PDF format and then insert them in a presentation (e.g., in Powerpoint), the plot axes are invisible in the picture created by the projector. Is there a way to impose a certain thickness to the axes?

Answer (score 5):

The option `AxesStyle -> Thick` will do